# Create elements using function parameters, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

First time question asker, go easy on me. I think I've thoroughly looked through Stack so as to not ask a repeated question.

I have a function.

```
function createDivs(num) {
    for(let inc = 0; inc < num; inc++) {
    let div = document.createElement('div'),
        tab_content = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');

        div.className = 'classname';
        div.id = `number-${inc}`;
        div.innerHTML = 'did it work?';
        tab_content.innerHTML = div;
    }
}
```

Where the HTML is just simply

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <script>
       createDivs(4);
    </script>
</div>
```

I've tried other methods like

```
let tab_content = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');

tab_content.innerHTML = '<div class="classname" id=`number-${inc}`>did it work?</div>';
```

as well as ton other variations with the `''` `""` and `` and that didn't work neither.

I have also tried `tab_content.appendChild(div);` and that didn't work either.

In reality this is a downgrade of what my actual code is because I'm creating tons of elements that need things in them, but I can't even get this bit to work. It doesn't even work if I remove the for loop. Also I did see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245654/dynamic-creating-elements-using-javascript), hence why I tried the appendChild, but again that also didn't work.

Comment: tab_content is an array there, not a single element; innerHTML takes a string, not an element; several variables are being declared in the global scope

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, which does not have an innerHTML property. You need to select a single node from that list, or iterate over each node and then set the innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want not to set the innerHTML, but actually to append several child nodes. In addition to that, there were a couple of errors in your code (getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, not just one object, so you'll need to select one to add your divs to.

Also, you named your i variable in the loop `inc` not i, so it doesn't actually increment the loop. Take a look at the below rewritten code and see if that does what you're looking for.

```js
function createDivs(num) {
    for(let inc = 0; inc < num; inc++) {
    let div = document.createElement('div'),
        tab_content = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');

        div.className = 'classname';
        div.id = `number-${inc}`;
        div.innerHTML = 'did it work?';
        tab_content[0].appendChild(div);
    }
}
(function(){createDivs(4)})()
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, the i++ was a typo, sorry about that ^__^" The actual code uses inc++ I fixed it. Haven't tried what you have suggested yet though so I'll will get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You had a few typos in your code. usin `i++` instead of `inc++` in  your loop. Not accessing tab_content as an array and using `innerHtml` instead of `appendChild`. Fixed code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createDivs(num) {
            for(let inc = 0; inc < num; inc++) {
            let div = document.createElement('div'),
                tab_content = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content')[0];

                div.className = 'classname';
                div.id = `number-${inc}`;
                div.innerHTML = 'did it work?';
                tab_content.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab-content">
    <script>
       createDivs(4);
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, the i++ was a typo, sorry about that ^__^" The actual code uses inc++ I fixed it. Haven't tried what you have suggested yet though so I'll will get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop does not increment its control variable. Change it to

```
   for(let inc = 0; inc < num; inc++) {
```

and `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object, not a single element. So you need to change it to

```
   tab_content = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content')[0];
```